# Active Admin form displays only "#<Keyword:0x10c858858>"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord, activeadmin

I am working on a HABTM relation in Active Admin. I have two models: `magazine.rb` and `keyword.rb`, both are related through a join table `magazines_keyword.rb`. I would like to be able to select in Active Admin keywords from the magazine resource page.

The AA resource file `magazines.rb` is as follows:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Magazine do
menu :priority => 1

form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
    f.inputs "Magazine Details" do
        f.input :title_id, :label => 'Title', :as => :select, :collection => Keyword.all.map{ |u| ["#{u.word.capitalize}", u.id] }
        f.input :keywords, :as => :check_boxes, :input_html => { :multiple => true } do
            f.has_many :keywords do |s|
                s.input :keyword, :collection => Keyword.all.map { |kw| ["#{kw.word.capitalize}", kw.id] }
            end
        end
    end
    f.actions
end

show do
    panel "Magazine Details" do
        attributes_table_for magazine do
            row "Keywords", :keyword do |m|
                m.keywords.map { |d| d.word }.join(", ").html_safe
            end
        end
    end
    active_admin_comments
end
```

The show part works. With this setting I am also able to input a new magazine and the join-table is written, but the form does not display the keywords, but only `#<Keyword:0x11adf6608>`. Which is what? The Active Records address for the field?

How can I get the form to display the right data entry for each record instead?

When I use:

```
f.input :keywords, :as => :check_boxes, :input_html => { :multiple => true }, :collection => Keyword.all.map { |kw| ["#{kw.word.capitalize}", kw.id] }
```

The keywords are displayed, but the join table appears not to be working, since I an unable to read, edit or write, new or already existing entries.

How can I get this part working?

**UPDATE**

When I create a new magazine entry with

`f.input :keywords, :as => :check_boxes`

```
Started GET "/admin/magazines/new" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat Mar 03 14:14:55 +0100 2018
Processing by Admin::Magazines Controller#new as HTML
  [1m[35mAdminUser Load (0.5ms)[0m  SELECT admin_users.* FROM admin_users WHERE admin_users.id = 1 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mKeyword Load (1.5ms)[0m  [1mSELECT keywords.* FROM keywords [0m
  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT keywords.* FROM keywords 
  Rendered /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/xxxxx/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/app/views/active_admin/resource/new.html.arb (378.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 387ms (Views: 380.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)


Started POST "/admin/magazines" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat Mar 03 14:15:09 +0100 2018
Processing by Admin::Magazines Controller#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"zzzzz=", "commit"=>"Create Magazine", "utf8"=>"✓", "Magazine"=>{"number"=>"10", "keyword_ids"=>["", "1", "2"], "description"=>"3", "colour"=>"4", "title_id"=>"1", "cover_alt"=>"5", "short"=>"2"}}
  [1m[36mAdminUser Load (0.5ms)[0m  [1mSELECT admin_users.* FROM admin_users WHERE admin_users.id = 1 LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mKeyword Load (0.4ms)[0m  SELECT keywords.* FROM keywords WHERE keywords.id IN (1, 2)
  [1m[36mSQL (0.1ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (1.2ms)[0m  INSERT INTO magazines (colour, cover_alt, created_at, description, number, short, title_id, updated_at) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["colour", "4"], ["cover_alt", "5"], ["created_at", Sat, 03 Mar 2018 13:15:09 UTC +00:00], ["description", "3"], ["number", 10], ["short", "2"], ["title_id", 1], ["updated_at", Sat, 03 Mar 2018 13:15:09 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[36m (0.3ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO magazines_keywords (magazine_id, keyword_id) VALUES (13, 1)[0m
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  INSERT INTO magazines_keywords (magazine_id, keyword_id) VALUES (13, 2)
  [1m[36m (6.1ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/admin/safts/13
Completed 302 Found in 29ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

And with:

```
f.input :keywords, :as => :check_boxes, :input_html => { :multiple => true } do
    f.has_many :keywords do |s|
        s.input :keyword, :collection => Keyword.all.map { |kw| ["#{kw.word.capitalize}", kw.id] }
    end
end
```

I get:

```
Started GET "/admin/magazines/new" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat Mar 03 14:21:41 +0100 2018
Processing by Admin::MagazinesController#new as HTML
  [1m[36mAdminUser Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT 'admin_users'.* FROM 'admin_users' WHERE 'admin_users'.'id' = 1 LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mKeyword Load (1.4ms)[0m  SELECT 'keywords'.* FROM 'keywords' 
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT 'keywords'.* FROM 'keywords' [0m
  Rendered /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/xxxxx/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/app/views/active_admin/resource/new.html.arb (300.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 390ms (Views: 302.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)


Started POST "/admin/magazines" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat Mar 03 14:21:54 +0100 2018
Processing by Admin::MagazinesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"zzzzz=", "commit"=>"Create Magazine", "utf8"=>"✓", "magazine"=>{"number"=>"11", "keyword_ids"=>["", "1", "2"], "description"=>"4", "colour"=>"5", "title_id"=>"2", "cover_alt"=>"6", "short"=>"3"}}
  [1m[35mAdminUser Load (0.4ms)[0m  SELECT 'admin_users'.* FROM 'admin_users' WHERE 'admin_users'.'id' = 1 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mKeyword Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT 'keywords'.* FROM 'keywords' WHERE 'keywords'.'id' IN (1, 2)[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.1ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36mSQL (0.9ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO 'magazines' ('colour', 'cover_alt', 'created_at', 'description', 'number', 'short', 'title_id', 'updated_at') VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)[0m  [["colour", "5"], ["cover_alt", "6"], ["created_at", Sat, 03 Mar 2018 13:21:54 UTC +00:00], ["description", "4"], ["number", 11], ["short", "3"], ["title_id", 2], ["updated_at", Sat, 03 Mar 2018 13:21:54 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  INSERT INTO 'magazines_keywords' ('magazine_id', 'keyword_id') VALUES (14, 1)
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO 'magazines_keywords' ('magazine_id', 'keyword_id') VALUES (14, 2)[0m
  [1m[35m (12.1ms)[0m  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/admin/magazines/14
Completed 302 Found in 114ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Try to leave only `f.input :keywords, :as => :check_boxes` and remove the rest (includes nested input)

Comment: Thank you for your input. I tried that, but it puts out the same strange string (Active Record key:value???). I ended up with a nested input, since I thought I had to get the keyword with something like `keyword.word.capitalize`. I am quite stuck here.

Comment: And what is in your `permit_params` section of `magazines.rb`? When you use `f.input :keywords, :as => :check_boxes, :input_html => { :multiple => true }, :collection => Keyword.all.map { |kw| ["#{kw.word.capitalize}", kw.id] }` and try to add some keywords to the magazine, don't you have some `Unpermitted params` in the server log?

Comment: You mean in the AA resource.rb? I have no permit_params, since the Rails version does not have permit_params. When I tried to add it, I got: `"undefined method permit_params for #<ActiveAdmin::ResourceDSL:0x11342b788>"`

Comment: I meant https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html#setting-up-strong-parameters

Comment: You've added a log for `Admin::Magazines Controller#show`, not `#create` :)

Comment: Looking to the log, all is working now - INSERT INTO magazines_keywords (magazine_id, keyword_id) VALUES (13, 2).

Comment: But you have a strange output, instead of a keyword name, yes?

Comment: f.input :keywords, as: :check_boxes, member_label: :word

Comment: f.input :keywords, as: :check_boxes, member_label: Proc.new { |kw| kw.word.capitalize }

Comment: The association is written, but in the view beside the checkbox I do not get the name of the keyword, but something like `#<Keyword:0x11adf6608>. Now that you ask: he probably does not get to the keyword table, but writes an address?

Comment: YEAHHHHHHHHH. `f.input :keywords, as: :check_boxes, member_label: :word` already did it! If you write a short answer I would be glad to accept it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help you :) If you will have problems with AA views syntax you maybe find an answer in Formtastic docs - https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use:

```
f.input :keywords, as: :check_boxes, member_label: :word
```

or

```
f.input :keywords, as: :check_boxes, member_label: Proc.new { |kw| kw.word.capitalize }
```